# Changing int values of nested map using iterator depending on key string

Tags: c++, dictionary, nested, key, increment

I currently have the following map

```
typedef map<int, int> inner;
map<string, inner> example;

example["hello"][1] = 100; 
example["hi"][2] = 200; //need to increment 2 to 3, and increase by 200
example["bye"][3] = 300;
example["ace"][4] = 400;
```

What I want to do is modify values of the inner map, I am currently trying the following

```
int size; //second int in inner map
int count; //first int in inner map

for (map<string, inner>::iterator it = example.begin(); it != example.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " ;
        for (inner::iterator it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); it2++)
        { 
            if (it->first.compare("hi")) //if at key "hi" 
            { 
                count = it2->first + 1;//increment by one
                size = it2->second + 200;//add 200
                example.erase("hi"); //remove this map entry
                example["hi"][count] = size; //re-add the map entry with updated values
            }

        }
```

I have tried a few different ways of doing this, but I definitely feel like I'm not understanding how the pointers are working. My output says that the count value is 2, and size is 300 (values modified at key "hello")

Comment: You cannot modify key, you may want `std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, int>>`

Comment: How would I go about adding values to that? I am trying: example.insert("hello", make_pair(1, 100)); and it isnt working

Comment: `example.insert({"hello", {1, 100}});` or `example["hello"] = {1, 100};`

Comment: Excellent! I have one more problem and then its smooth sailing. I notice that pairs dont use iterators, so how would I alter my nested for loop? Thanks guys!

Comment: You don't need a nested loop. There's only 1 container now. Just get rid of the nested loop. `it2->first` becomes `it->second.first`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the info given in the comments:

If you have a size and count mapped to a string, name the size and count something that makes sense and make it a struct:

```
struct Stats {
    int size;
    int count;
};

std::map<std::string, Stats> example;

example["hello"] = {1, 100};
example["hi"] = {2, 200};
```

If you want to find the value at key "hi":

```
auto it = example.find("hi");
if (it != example.end()) {
    ++it->second.count;
    it->second.size += 200;
}
```

If you want to print all the elements:

```
for (auto& i : example) {
    std::cout << i.first << " = {"
              << i.second.size << ", "
              << i.second.count << "}\n";
}
```

Comment: it->second.size += 200 just increments size to 202, doesn't add to 400. Can't figure out why this is.

Comment: @ChandlerPavia Because size started at 2 and counted started at 200... comeon man.